# Redirect to a different URL after submitting the form with jQuery Validate submitHandler (Without Ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, webhooks

I have a problem with making a form on Wordpress website work with two tools: Zapier and AutopilotHQ. I want my form to be submitted to myWebHookURL but the page to be redirected to a different url, not myWebHookURL. I can't use Ajax (AutopilotHQ doesn't work with it) and I can't use iframes. If there's a way to do it with PHP I'd like to know how.

Form attributes:

```
<form id="myForm" action="https://myWebHookURL" method="POST"  name="myForm">
```

After clicking the submit input I validate it using jQuery plugin and submit it the form using form.submit in the submitHandler function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('#myForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    }).validate({
    rules:{
      ...},
    messages:{
      ...},
    submitHandler: function(form){
      form.submit();
  }});
});
```

Right now my page redirect's to the url attached to the action attribute. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: After the form.submit() you can just use javascript to redirect => window.location = "http://www.example.com";

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this doesn't work because form.submit() takes the user to another page and the rest of the code is never executed. Same for putting this line before the form.submit(). :< thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you control myWebHookURL then you could accept the form data and then redirect to your desired url.

On the other hand, if you don't control myWebHookURL because it's hosted elsewhere, like Zapier, then I would handle the form post in a new url you control, post the relevant data to the webhook from the code you control in php, and then redirect to your desired destination url.

Pseudo code :

```
Repackage post data
Post the data to the webhook url (use guzzle for example, or some other http wrapper)
Redirect to desired destination (header('location: destUrl'))
```

Comment: Hi RichGoldMD, thank you for taking your time to answer my question. I fixed the issue exactly like you explained it. For anyone having this issue, this article helped me as well: [link](https://www.automationfuel.com/zapier-webhook-post-example-tutorial/)